# Create a report that will display all contracts with six months remaining before their expiration dates

Tags: reporting, formula-field

This seems like a very simple question, but I am quite confused. I am using standard Contract object, and I created a formula field `Half Year Expiration Date` which has a formula of `EndDate - 182.5`. 182.5 is the total of all days in 6 months (given that contract term is 12 months) based on my estimate.

How do I use this in a report such that all contracts with six months remaining before their expiration dates are displayed?

Answer (score 1):

I think your requirement can be met by using a relative date filter on Contract end date which will save you an extra field.  This example will show all contracts that have an end date greater than 6 months from today.

If you want those ending before then you would adjust the filter.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_dates_relative.htm&type=5

[image]